# how to create a middleware In laravel 10 to log all API request & response in database table?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have an API project on Laravel lumen which is already built with approx 300 API URLs. Now the requirement is to store every request and its response to the database to track the API calls.
There is any package or short solution for that to store it without changing any API function directly or one by one?

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a middleware what wraps around all your requests.

```php
class LoggerMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $response = $next($request);

            $this->logSuccess($request, $response);

            return $response;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $this->logFailure($request, $ex);
            throw $ex;
        }
    }

    public function logSuccess($request, $response)
    {
        // Log to database
    }

    public function logFailure($request, $exception)
    {
        // Log to database
    }
}
```

In Laravel add your middleware in `App\Http\Kernel` and `routes/*.php` or `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`

In Lumen you should register your middleware like this instead:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#registering-middleware

```
// bootstrap/app.php

$app->middleware([
   App\Http\Middleware\LoggerMiddleware::class
]);
```